# Making Postgres accessible in Firefox by Psql

Tags: installation, mediawiki, postgresql

**How can you make Postgres accessible in Firefox, in installing MediaWiki?**

I get the error "No database connection" because Firefox cannot have a database connection. 
I can have database connection in terminal by the user, masi.
This suggests me that Firefox is not acting like a masi, so it cannot have the access.

Error

```
Warning: pg_version(): supplied argument is not a valid PostgreSQL link resource in /var/www/wiki/includes/db/DatabasePostgres.php on line 1078
FAILED. Required version is 8.1. You have 7.3 or earlier
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox is irrelevant. It's webserver that makes the connection. If you can connect from local shell (via psql), but can't from webserver then:

1. show us the error you're getting
2. show us pg_hba.conf

Then maybe we can help.

Besides - for diagnosing problems you'd me **much** better off with asking on irc - server irc.freenode.net, channel #postgresql.